# How do I open a checked out file in a Perforce depot with an external editor on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, text-editors, sandbox, perforce

I'm using p4v on OS X 10.8. Before I upgraded to Mountain Lion, I could double click a checked out file in a changelist under the "Pending" tab and the file would open in the external editor specified in p4v settings (MacVim for example).

In Mountain Lion, double clicking the checked out file gets the GateKeeper message of "FilenameHere can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."  Pretty weird that it says the *text file* is from an unidentified developer rather than the application attempting to open it.

Does anyone know how to work around the new sandbox in Mountain Lion and open checked out files in an external editor from the Perforce Visual Client?  Even specifying the native app TextEdit doesn't work.  Is this possible without turning off GateKeeper?

Comment: This does not seem to be limited to perforce. I am seeing the same problem with a registry file copied from a Windows system.